# Android : Camera running on asynctask and taking autophotos

Tags: android, android-asynctask, camera

I need to build an app with a camera that takes automatically pictures. I was wondering if it is possible to make the camera take those pictures in AsyncTask, so the camera would not open to the user, it would just take the pictures to be used in a project that i am working.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask's are meant for short asynchronous tasks. I'm assuming that you want the camera to take shots on a set interval for longer periods of time.
Why not implement this in a service?

Comment: Yes, that is what i need to do. Do you have an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run it in a service.
There is a good example of how to do this here. This examples explains how to capture images in background.
http://androideasylessons.blogspot.com/2012/09/capture-image-without-surface-view-as.html